# Filter Series/DataFrame by another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Let's suppose I have a Series (or DataFrame) `s1`, for example list of all Universities and Colleges in the USA:

```
                     University
0            Searcy Harding University
1          Angwin Pacific Union College
2    Fairbanks University of Alaska Fairbanks
3        Ann Arbor University of Michigan
```

And another Series (od DataFrame) `s2`, for example list of all cities in the USA:

```
      City
0    Searcy
1    Angwin 
2   New York 
3   Ann Arbor
```

And my desired output (bascially an intersection of `s1` and `s2`):

```
     Uni City
0     Searcy
1     Angwin 
2    Fairbanks 
3    Ann Arbor
```

The thing is: I'd like to create a Series that consists of **cities** but only these, that have a university/college. My very first thought was to remove "University" or "College" parts from the `s1`, but it turns out that it is not enough, as in case of `Angwin Pacific Union College`. Then I thought of leaving only the first word, but that excludes `Ann Arbor`. 
Finally, I got a series of all the cities `s2` and now I'm trying to use it as a filter (something similiar to `.contains()` or `.isin()`), so if a string `s1` (Uni name) contains **any** of the elements of `s2` (city name), then return only the city name.

My question is: how to do it in a neat way?

Comment: @AlexandreB. sure. Edited.

Comment: You said your desired output is an intersection of `s1` and `s2`, but `Fairbanks` is not in `s2`?

Comment: @thesecond, see my answer and let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to build a list comprehension of cities that are contained in at least one university name:

```
pd.Series([i for i in s2 if s1.str.contains(i).any()], name='Uni City')
```

With your example data it gives:

```
0       Searcy
1       Angwin
2    Ann Arbor
Name: Uni City, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Data Used

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'University':['Searcy Harding University','Angwin Pacific Union College','Fairbanks University of Alaska Fairbanks','Ann Arbor University of Michigan']})


s2=pd.DataFrame({'City':['Searcy','Angwin','Fairbanks','Ann Arbor']})
```

Convert `s2.City` to set to create an iterator

```
st=set(s2.City.unique().tolist())
```

Calculate `s['Uni City']` using the next() function to return the next item from the iterator.

```
s['Uni City']=s['University'].apply(lambda x: next((i for i in st if i in x)), np.nan)
```

Outcome

[image]